# “Find My Device” equivalent for Linux

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, debian, icloud

I’m thinking of switching to Linux (either Debian or Ubuntu, haven’t decided) from macOS. One of the features of macOS I love is “Find My Device,” which allows me to locate my device if I lose it, remotely play a sound bypassing Do Not Disturb, erase my device remotely (while still preventing other people from using it through “Activation Lock”), and displaying a message to any passerby. Is this possible on Debian or Ubuntu? If so, what package can I use? I’d prefer for it to be self-hosted (am averse to sharing my location with random, unknown companies) and free software (both in price and freedom).

Comment: There is no equivalent.

Comment: Is there a package to do it though @ChanganAuto?

Answer (score 1):

There are additions to Linux, such as free [Pombo](https://github.com/BoboTiG/pombo/tree/master/gui) and commercial subscription services [Prey](https://preyproject.com/) and [DriveStrike](https://drivestrike.com/how-to/remote-wipe-linux/). Some, like *Prey*, offer both location tracking and data destruction, others just one or the other. You might find other recommendations at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

You might also research Linux versions that are or can be made compliant with [Federal Information Processing Standards (FIPS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standards), such as [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/sect-security_guide-federal_standards_and_regulations-federal_information_processing_standard), [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/security/certifications), or [CentOS](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-make-centos-rhel-7-fips-140-2-compliant/). Given sufficiently-effective encryption, low-value data should be safe.

All this said, security is a *major* concern and undertaking, far beyond the scope of a simple recommendation. If you are serious about security and care to pay for it, you might consult IT security services.

Comment: I'd prefer something that doesn't require a thief to not erase the drive (i.e. a stupid thief); I'd like something a bit more secure. Regardless, I'll be migrating this question to AskUbuntu.

Comment: Or, apparently SE Linux and Unix.